# How does DownForEveryoneOrJustMe.com and other similar sites work with Cross Domain Scripting restrictions?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, onload

I would like to make a simple website that allows the user to enter a URL, click a button, and if the URL loads successfully, alert the user. Something like the site http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ (or for a fancier version http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/).

Javascript, specifically XmlHttpRequest(), does not seem to be an option due to Cross-Domain Scripting restrictions. A similar issue occurs through use of hidden iframes or windows and the onLoad() event.

My question is - how do these sites work given the restrictions on cross-domain scripting? What's the key piece of technology I'm missing here?

Comment: Request is made on the server...The serverside has no same origin rules to follow. If it was made on the client it is no different than you hitting the server.

Answer (score 3):

These sites get around the restrictions on cross domain scripting by not making their requests using the browser - they don't load the URL on the client side. Instead, the user sends a request to the webserver, the webserver runs a server-side script to try and access the provided URL, and informs the user if its attempt was successful.

The question they're answering is "Can someone other than me access this site?" Making the person asking the question try and access the site wouldn't answer that question.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I suppose that makes sense to me. So would something like Node JS be a way to do this? Use Node JS to create a web server?

Comment: I don't think you would need to create a whole web server to do this, just write a script in Node JS that executes on your server, performs the request, and returns the result. But yes, node JS would be an appropriate technology for the problem! (Probably, I don't have any experience in it.)

Edit: Oh, this looks like what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332994/check-if-website-is-contactable